# How to remove putrescine odour

Tags: biochemistry

Does anyone know how to remove the odour remaining from a decomposed corpse which has fallen onto a wooden floor? Aparently the two main chemicals are putrescine (tetramethylenediamine) and cadaverine (pentamethylenediamine).

Comment: Both of those are amines so repeated washes with dilute acid (maybe vinegar) should help.

Comment: Thanks. So using bases such as Sodium hydroxide would not be the thing to do.

Comment: No, not at all. Bleach is another possibly taking the amines to the amine oxides

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6290/what-causes-the-smell-in-rotten-meat-grease-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-it-thorough